# getting a restful Api using the fetch() in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

im really going through hard times trying to figure out how to get my API data through Vuex, is there some body whom has accurate bibliography of how to do this step by step, or even better help me with this code?
Formerly without using Vuex , but Vue all request worked perfectly, but now i dont understand clearly what i should do, here sharing part of my code:

```
data() {
    return {
      testArray: []
    }; 
 methods: {

    getJsonData() {
      fetch(
        "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?countryCode=" +
          this.countriesDrop +
          "&apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        {
          method: "GET"
        }
      )
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(test => {console.log(this.testArray)
          this.testArray = test._embedded.events;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
    watch: {
    countriesDrop: function(val) {
         this.getJsonData();
    }
  },
```

As you can see in the request also is included an external element which make it changes attuning with the watcher and the value the user might asign.
I already got set Vuex and all else pluggins...just dont know how to act like , thus would appreciate an accurate link or tutorial either help with this basic problem resolved on detail step by step, .....thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve with this code. What is the **watch**er for? Where does `this.countriesDrop` come from? What does it have to do with **Vuex**?

Comment: the watcher simply attends from a dropdown list selector which attuning with the user selection  my change the API request to a different country code in this case...and i suppose if we import the whole Api request to Vuex that element modifying the request also should be imported

Answer (score 1):

In your code there's nothing with **Vuex**. I guessed you want to set the state so that the `getJsonData()` method is called according to what's in the **store**.

Here's a snippet as an example of handling async in a **Vuex** environment.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    testArray: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setTestArray(state, data) {
      state.testArray = data
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getJsonData({
      commit
    }, countriesDrop) {
      if (countriesDrop && countriesDrop !== '') {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${countriesDrop}`, {
            method: "GET"
          })
          .then(response => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(json => {
            commit('setTestArray', json)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  computed: {
    getDataFromStore() {
      return this.$store.state.testArray
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData(countriesDrop) {
      this.$store.dispatch('getJsonData', countriesDrop)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="getData('todos')">GET TODOS</button>
  <button @click="getData('albums')">GET ALBUMS</button>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="data in getDataFromStore">{{data.title}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

The point is that **Vuex** is a central element in a Vue-Vuex application. You can store app state, handle async and sync functions (actions, mutations) with it, and all your Vue components can rely on the state - that should be the "single source of truth".

So, you get your input from a component (the Vue instance in this snippet), and **dispatch** an **action** that is available in the Vuex store. If the **action** needs to modify the state, then you call a **mutation** to do that. With this *flow* you keep reactivity for all your components that use that state.

I used a **computed** to get data from the Vuex store, but **getters** can be set also.

This way you don't "pollute" your components with functions and data that should be in the store.